# Storing images locally with ActiveAdmin Editor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I'm using ActiveAdmin editor ( https://github.com/ejholmes/active_admin_editor ) in my Rails 4 application. Currently, the gem is supporting only images from other sources (I can link an image url to a blog post, for example).

Also, the initializer config of the Editor allows optional s3 upload. Any solution to get this working in storing the images in, for example, image table. Is this even a good idea?

Here's the code from the initializer:

```
ActiveAdmin::Editor.configure do |config|
  # config.s3_bucket = ''
  # config.aws_access_key_id = ''
  # config.aws_access_secret = ''
  # config.storage_dir = 'uploads'
end
```

Thank you so much!